# excluding CarPlay stuff from Apple TV destination

Tags: ios, swift, television, carplay

I have a multi-platform app for iOS, and Mac Catalyst. I'm trying to include Apple TV, but it says `No such module 'CarPlay'` when I try to build.

Since Apple TV is not a Target, how can I exclude the CarPlay stuff from the Apple TV ?

```
import CarPlay

class CarPlaySceneDelegate: UIResponder, CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate {
    var interfaceController: CPInterfaceController?
    func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
        self.interfaceController = interfaceController
        let nowPlaying = CPNowPlayingTemplate.shared
        self.interfaceController?.setRootTemplate(nowPlaying, animated: true, completion: {_, _ in })
    }
    private func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didDisconnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
        self.interfaceController = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tvOS is a separate operating system and Swift support conditional compilation based on the targeted OS, so you can declare your code that uses `CarPlay` to only be available when not targeting `tvOS`.

```
#if !os(tvOS)
import CarPlay

class CarPlaySceneDelegate: UIResponder, CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate {
...
}

#endif
```

You could also use `#if canImport(CarPlay)` instead.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend using `canImport`... this would have saved me so much time adding the visionOS target

Comment: ah yes, I didn't realise you could add tvOS as a Target - I was just selecting it as a run destination in the project settings